# A weird thick line under text

Tags: html, css, font-face, webfonts, truetype

I am trying to make a portfolio site for a school project and this is what it looks like under normal resolution

[image]

Looks normal right? However when I zoom out a weird thick line appears under the text

[image]

Here's the HTML and CSS code.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'KGDefyingGravity';
  src: url(../fonts/KGDefyingGravity.ttf);
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'KGDefyingGravity';
  font-size: 6em;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(15, 0, 223);
  letter-spacing: -1px;
}

.selection {
  font-family: 'KGDefyingGravity';
  font-size: 5em;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(223, 0, 15);
  letter-spacing: -1px;
}
```

```html
<h1>[|||||||'S|PORTFOLIO|SITE]</h1>
<a href="\index.html" class="selection">[HOME|PAGE]</a>
```

EDIT: I have no idea why my code is a code snippet. The site just seemed to automatically do that.

Comment: just add `text-decoration:none` to `.selection`

Comment: @ZohirSalak Thanks, it seems to work now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably default user agent stylesheet contains

> text-decoration: underline;

To avoid this you should put

> text-decoration: none;

inside the selector of DOM element.

For example:

```
h1 {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

I hope that I helped ;)

Comment: you meant `a{}` not `h1{}` ?

Comment: a is for hyperlink; h1 is for first level header

Comment: `text-decoration: underline;` is on the hyperline

Comment: Ok, sorry for my mistake :/